# How can I get AWS credentials through Cognito identity pool?

Tags: c++, amazon-cognito, identity, credentials

I'd like to know how I can get temporary AWS credentials through Amazon Cognito Identity pool (in C/C++)?

From the link (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication-flow.html), it seems we could get the credentials by only providing the Identity Pool ID and the region to the application, but after some checking of the aws-sdk-cpp SDK (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp), it seems no direct way&example to do this.

So I'd like to know if anyone here knows about this and give me some guidance? Thanks in advance! :)